# raspberry pi sound based traffic lights

Tags: python, multithreading, raspberry-pi, sensors

I am trying to implement a sensor-based traffic light for a school project. By that I mean, there is a sound sensor LM393 that acts as a switch. When it detects a sound, it will change the sequence of the traffic lights. For example, the traffic light would be something like this: Red LED for 2 sec, turn off red, yellow LED for 2 sec, turn off yellow, green led for 2 sec, turn off green, then this cycle repeats itself. If a sound is detected, the sequence is interrupted and the green light immediately becomes green for 5 sec and then the normal cycle starts again.

This is what I have so far:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from time import sleep
from threading import Thread
from gpiozero import LED
#GPIO SETUP
red = LED(17)
gre=LED(24)
yel = LED(27)
channel = 23
emer_detec = False

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(channel, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down = GPIO.PUD_UP)

def sound():
    GPIO.add_event_detect(channel, GPIO.BOTH, bouncetime=1000)  # let us know when the pin goes HIGH or LOW
    GPIO.add_event_callback(channel, callback)  # assign function to GPIO PIN, Run function on change

def regular():
    while True:
       
        if not GPIO.input(channel):            
            red.on()
            sleep(2)
            red.off()
           
            yel.on()
            sleep(2)
            yel.off()
            
            gre.on()
            sleep(2)
            gre.off()
        
def callback(channel):
    print('Emergency vehicle detected')
    red.off()
    yel.off()
    gre.on()
    sleep(5)
    gre.off()
        
sound_thread= Thread(target=sound)
sound_thread.daemon= True
sound_thread.start()

regular_thread= Thread(target=regular)
regular_thread.daemon= True
regular_thread.start()

# infinite loop
while True:
    pass
```

At first, the two threads are running in parallel when there is a sound and all lights go off as expected. However, when the green light is turned on, the normal cycle is also running. How can I stop the normal cycle thread when the other thread is working? Is there any way to do this without using threads?

Comment: It's been a while since I've done raspberry pi stuff, but if I remember correctly you only need to call `GPIO.add_event_detect` and `GPIO.add_event_callback` once, not over and over in a loop, so there would be no need for threading,

Comment: That part is for the sound detection. my issue is for the two cycles overlapping with each other. I want to stop the regular cycle when the traffic one is working, and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

One quick way to solve this might be to have some kind of global flag that handles the state of the system. For example,

```py
IS_REGULAR = True

def regular():
    while True:
        if not GPIO.input(channel) and not IS_REGULAR:            
            for col in [red, yel, gre]:
                col.on()
                sleep(2)
                col.off()
                if not IS_REGULAR: break
        
def callback(channel):
    global IS_REGULAR
    IS_REGULAR = False

    print('Emergency vehicle detected')
    red.off()
    yel.off()
    gre.on()
    sleep(5)
    gre.off()

    IS_REGULAR = True
```

Comment: The only issue is that multithreading is often tricky when you are trying to share data between threads. So as your code stands right now, this may not help. It's possible you could need to remove the `sound_thread` and `regular_thread` parts and simply call `sound()` and then `regular()`. From my understanding, the `callback` function is called automatically whenever there is a GPIO callback due to `GPIO.add_event_callback` having been called in `sound`.

Comment: Hi Jaedon, thank you very much for your elegant code. I followed your approach and could solve my Issue.